# How to adjust the width of a label inside a div inside an li?

Tags: css, label, width, html-lists

I've been working on this problem for 3 hours trying all sorts of ways.

The width works fine if I change

```
#todo-list li label{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

but I just want it to be word-wrap: normal.

See http://jsfiddle.net/adriennetran/svjbnxLp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove:

```
#todo-list li {
     white-space: nowrap;
}
#todo-list li label {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svjbnxLp/1/

Comment: OK so the problem is I need "white-space: pre;" for new lines to be recognized in the textarea submit.

If I remove "white-space: pre;", it word wraps correct, but new lines are not recognized

Comment: -EDIT- oh you can do "pre-line" instead of "pre" Perfect.